# How to get all Users in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

How can I get a list of all users in a controller?

I googled and only found solutions for ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: can you provide more information on what kind of project you are setting up? identity?

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because it really hasn't changed. Assuming you're using Identity:

```
var users = await context.Users.ToListAsync();
```

`IdentityDbContext<TUser>` has a `DbSet<TUser>` property named `Users` as it always had. You can utilize it just like any other `DbSet`.

Comment: You don't. You inject it into your controller's constructor. The DI container takes care of instantiating it.

Comment: I don't think there is a ToListAsync, just ToList, so you can't do await.

Comment: @Diomedes You have to add the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore using. Otherwise, all you're see is the LINQ version of ToList, which will end up calling the EF Core ToList, which ironically blocks on ToListAsync.